# rspec expects all :resources to equal resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm new to RSpec, I wonder why I didn't pass this test

```
before(:each) { get :index }

it "assigns all favorites as @favorites" do
  favorite = FactoryGirl.create(:favorite)
  expect(assigns(:favorites)).to eq([favorite])
end
```

It says

```
1) FavoritesController GET index assigns all favorites as @favorites
   Failure/Error: expect(assigns(:favorites)).to eq([favorite])

     expected: [#<Favorite id: 1, patient_id: 6, doctor_id: 5>]
          got: #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>                                           

     (compared using ==)

     Diff:                                                                                    
     @@ -1,2 +1,2 
     -[#<Favorite:0x000000058a5ca0 id: 1, patient_id: 6, doctor_id: 5>]
     +[]
```

It seems `assigns(:favorites)` got empty. I have tried another approach as well

```
def valid_attributes
  doctor = FactoryGirl.create(:doctor)
  patient = FactoryGirl.create(:patient)
  FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:favorite, doctor_id: doctor.id, patient_id: patient.id)
end

it "assigns all favorites as @favorites" do
  favorite = Favorite.create! valid_attributes
  expect(assigns(:favorites)).to eq([favorite])
end
```

And it got the same error. Any inputs would be helpful for me and I'd like to ask if there is any way to simplify it.

**Update**

app/controllers/favorite_controller.rb

```
class FavoritesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_favorite, only: [:destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @favorites = Favorite.where(:patient_id => current_user.id).order(id: :asc)
  end
end
```

spec/controllers/favorite_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe FavoritesController, type: :controller do

  login_patient

  describe "GET index" do
    let!(:favorite) { FactoryGirl.create(:favorite) }
    before { get :index }

    it { expect(response).to render_template(:index) }
    it { expect(response).to be_success }
    it { expect(response).to have_http_status(200) }

    it "blocks unauthenticated access", :skip_before do
      expect(response).to redirect_to(new_user_session_path)
    end

    it "assigns all favorites as @favorites" do
      expect(assigns(:favorites).to_a).to eq([favorite])
    end
  end
end
```

spec/support/controller_helpers.rb

```
module ControllerHelpers
  def login_patient
    before :each do |example|
      unless example.metadata[:skip_before]
        @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
        @patient = FactoryGirl.create(:patient)
        sign_in :user, @patient
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create the records before the request:

```
let!(:favorite) { FactoryGirl.create(:favorite) }
before(:each) { get :index }

it "assigns all favorites as @favorites" do
  expect(assigns(:favorites).to_a).to eq([favorite])
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the records after you send the request so by the time the request finishes, the record you just created isn't included in the list of favorites.  Change your test code to the following

```
let!(:favorite) { FactoryGirl.create(:favorite) }

before { get :index }

it "assigns all favorites as @favorites" do
  expect(assigns(:favorites)).to eq([favorite])
end
```

This will probably still fail because `assigns(:favorites)` is an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object so you have to call `to_a`

```
expect(assigns(:favorites).to_a).to eq([favorite])
```

UPDATE:

Since the favorite is being filtered by patient, you have to make sure that the created favorite in the test belongs to the patient.  You can do that by changing the favorite to

```
let!(:favorite) { FactoryGirl.create(:favorite, patient: @patient)
```

Comment: I'll leave my comment here as both answers are same. I've tried it and still not pass. The only difference is now it gets empty `[]`

Comment: that means that you're somehow filtering the favorites in the index action OR the favorite isn't created at all.

Comment: @jnvill yes there is a filtering on controller. I just add the controller and update the full controller spec. I have a condition where it gets the value from devise `current_user`. The other tests are passed, except the one I asked before.

Comment: Thank you for your update, but when I try that it raises validation. It says patient can't be empty. Then I changed to `patient_id: @patient.id` now it says: undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

Comment: could you give me a clue how to debug it? I have no idea about it

Comment: search how to use `pry` or `byebug`.